# Why in the figma variables of the MUI design system, certain colors are put in the form of tokens and others are in the form of HEX code

Tags: material-ui, figma

Why in the figma variables of the MUI design system, certain colors are put in the form of tokens and others are in the form of HEX code ? Plz :D [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohCDW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qEKg.png)

I don't really understand the logic of colors in MUI variables

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, those variables that are not hex codes are referencing variables from another collection of variables.  The theory is that you would define your brand variables in one collection and then reference them in semantic tokens where applicable, so that if you make a change to any of those brand variables it will automagically cascade to all other uses.

This video explains it pretty dang well - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ONxxlJnvdM

Cheers!